# Eclipse JavaSE 1.8 - Version "SUNWprivate_1.1" not found

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, lwjgl, archlinux

I am using archlinux with kde plasma and I'm coding something in Eclipse using JavaSE 1.8_282 and every time I try to start the program this error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Project/liblwjgl64.so: /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507/jre/lib/libjawt.so: version `SUNWprivate_1.1' not found (required by Project/liblwjgl64.so)
```

I searched up the error and didn't find anything helpful.
I already tried reinstalling eclipse and java, didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @greg-449 It's not the minimal, but the full JDK that should be enough to run Eclipse and Java application from inside and outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Do you get the same on the command line for `/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507/jre/bin/javaw -version`?

Comment: Thanks very much to whoever (they deleted their comment it seems). The error was that it was using the integrated jre15 in eclipse and I have to set the correct jre manually in the preferences (even though the correct one is set in the build path). Everything works now :D